# Assistance in converting UML Diagram into Ruby Code

Tags: ruby, uml, diagram

[UML Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCRxE.jpg)

That is the link to my diagram.

Their are 3 classes.(Appointment, MonthlyAppointment, & OneTimeAppointment). I am lost at this point. I rewatched my lecture a couple of times, but I'm not able to get past this point. This is just a practice problem. Any step by step assistance would be very helpful.

This is the code that I have so far for each.

```
class Appointment 
  attr_accessor :location, :purpose, :hour, :min

  def initialize the_location, the_purpose, the_hour, the_min
    @location = the_location
    @purpose = the_purpose
    @hour = the_hour
    @min = the_min
  end 

  def to_s
  end    
end


class MonthlyAppointment
  attr_accessor :location, :purpose, :day, :hour, :min

  def initialize the_location, the_purpose, the_day, the_hour, the_min
    @location = the_location
    @purpose = the_purpose
    @hour = the_hour
    @min = the_min
  end

  def occurs_on?(the_year, the_month, the_day)
  return @day == the_day
  end
end


class OneTimeAppointment
  attr_accessor :year, :month, :day

  def initialize the_year, the_month, the_day
    @year = the_year
    @month = the_month
    @day = the_day
  end      

  def occurs_on?(the_year, the_month, the_day)
  return @year == the_year &&
         @month == the_month &&
         @day == the_day
  end      
end
```

**Edited Post**: Am I suppose to implement it like this...

```
 class Item
  def initialize(item_name, quantity)
    @item_name = item_name
    @quantity = quantity
  end

  def quantity=(new_quantity)
    @quantity = new_quantity
  end

  def quantity
    @quantity
  end  
end
```

Comment: What part in particular are you lost on? You seem to be on the right track. Do you need to implement the instance methods, or just define a class that has the correct interface?

Comment: Yes, I need to implement each class than set up a test.rb to check if it all works. But I'm stuck on the implementing part. is it suppose to go like this?

Comment: Can you help me with implementing the derived classes and also explain how you came to that solution?

Comment: Ok, I understand. I'm working on a longer answer with a lot of detail, sit tight.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take Monthly Appointment for an example. (I'll leave the other one for you so I'm not doing all your homework :) )

The top level class here is Appointment, which has fields and methods which are common
to the other two classes. So we can start there.

Let's define the class

```
class Appointment
end
```

it needs to have an initializer that takes a couple fields

```
class Appointment
  def initialize(the_location, the_purpose, the_hour, the_min)
  end
end
```

Now, since we have a class that we've defined the initializer on, ruby will give us the new method for free.

This class has a couple fields in it, location, purpose, hour, min. We can save those from the initializer into
instance variables.

```
class Appointment
  def initialize(the_location, the_purpose, the_hour, the_min)
    @location = the_location
    @purpose = the_purpose
    @hour = the_hour
    @min = the_min
  end
end
```

There. We now have all the fields, the new method and the initialize method. Next up we need location().
This is meant to be a getter, a method that gets the value of the field.

```
class Appointment
  def initialize(the_location, the_purpose, the_hour, the_min)
    @location = the_location
    @purpose = the_purpose
    @hour = the_hour
    @min = the_min
  end

  def location
    return @location
  end
end
```

There we go. But as it happens, because writing a getter like this is such a common task (we have to do it 5 times just in
this class), ruby has a much shorter way to do it. If we say attr_reader :location, ruby knows to define a method
just like the one above. So using that, our new class is this:

```
class Appointment
  attr_reader :location

  def initialize(the_location, the_purpose, the_hour, the_min)
    @location = the_location
    @purpose = the_purpose
    @hour = the_hour
    @min = the_min
  end
end
```

and we can do the same thing for the other four fields as well.

```
class Appointment
  attr_reader :location, :purpose, :hour, :min

  def initialize(the_location, the_purpose, the_hour, the_min)
    @location = the_location
    @purpose = the_purpose
    @hour = the_hour
    @min = the_min
  end
end
```

Okay, now we have everything except to_s(). to_s is a method that returns a string version of the appointment.
A roughly human readable description, basically. Let's define that

```
class Appointment
  attr_reader :location, :purpose, :hour, :min

  def initialize(the_location, the_purpose, the_hour, the_min)
    @location = the_location
    @purpose = the_purpose
    @hour = the_hour
    @min = the_min
  end

  def to_s
    "<Appointment #{@hour}:#{@min} at #{@location} for #{@purpose}>"
  end
end
```

That will give us a description something like "Appointment 2:34 at the office for progress update".
That looks good to me!

Now we're done with the Appointment class, lets do the MonthlyAppointment class.
It's clearly supposed to be a subclass of Appointment, even though your diagram doesn't show that.

```
class MonthlyAppointment < Appointment
end
```

So far so good. It has an initializer. Let's define that

```
class MonthlyAppointment < Appointment
  def initialize(the_location, the_purpose, the_day, the_hour, the_min)
  end
end
```

There, that meets what the UML specifies for the interface of initialize.
Now, we see that there is a field called "@day", and since the initializer has an argument for day,
we can save the value from the initializer. We also still want to save everything that the superclass
cares about too, so we call super to get the parent class's initializer to run too.

```
class MonthlyAppointment < Appointment
  def initialize(the_location, the_purpose, the_day, the_hour, the_min)
    super(the_location, the_purpose, the_hour, the_min)
    @day = the_day
  end
end
```

and we need a getter for the day field

```
class MonthlyAppointment < Appointment
  attr_reader :day

  def initialize(the_location, the_purpose, the_day, the_hour, the_min)
    super(the_location, the_purpose, the_hour, the_min)
    @day = the_day
  end
end
```

Lastly, we need to define occurs_on?. occurs_on? takes a year month and day and will return true or false.
Methods with a question mark should always return true or false.
Now, a monthly appointment happens every year, so we can ignore that for now.
It also happens every month, so we can ignore that. But it only happens on a specific day
every month, so let's compare the day that's being asked about with the day we saved.
If they match, then we should return true. Ex if you have a monthly appointment on the 15th,
you only have to know whether it's the 15th or not to know if it happens on a date.

```
class MonthlyAppointment < Appointment
  attr_reader :day

  def initialize(the_location, the_purpose, the_day, the_hour, the_min)
    super(the_location, the_purpose, the_hour, the_min)
    @day = the_day
  end

  def occurs_on?(the_year, the_mon, the_day)
    if @day == the_day
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

And voila! That should be your MonthlyAppointment class. Can you try to implement OneTimeAppointment?
If you post it here I'll give pointers.

Comment: Ya I def will. Im gonna read this over a couple of times then ill try it out my self and post it her when I finish. Thank you.